# Slider Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Estou desenvolvendo um slider onde preciso mostrar 4 imagens por vez, 2 em cima e 2 embaixo, utilizando  jquerUI slider, eu fiz um exemplo no jsfiddle, porem so estou conseguindo colocar todas em linha, exemplo no jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7xk6Y/

eu peguei esse exemplo na internet e estou tentando modificar da maneira que preciso..

Comment: Formate melhor sua pergunta e o título, "alguém?" parece que você abortou a frase. O que você está com dúvida? Como você fez? Como você tentou fazer?

Comment: @Strokes alterada a questao, você pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Furlan, do jeito que você montou, creio que não seja possível.

Tenta criar blocos com 4 imagens, e faça com que apareça um bloco por vez.

Atualizei seu código (http://jsfiddle.net/7xk6Y/5/), deixei duas imagens agora, só pra dar exemplo.

Dentro de um LI, procure deixar as 4 imagens e faça com que o slider exiba somente UM LI por vez.

Abraços